# asp.net dropdownlist and database weird issue

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, webforms

I have 2 dropdownlists and 2 issues. The first one is supposed to load with the employerID combined and displayed as seen here:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter daEmploy = new SqlDataAdapter(EmployCmd);
conn.Open();

daEmploy.Fill(ds, "EmployerID");

ddlCompanyList.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
ddlCompanyList.Items.Clear();
ddlCompanyList.Items.Add("--Please Select the Company--");
ddlCompanyList.DataTextField = "EmployerID";
ddlCompanyList.DataValueField = "EmployerID";
ddlCompanyList.DataBind();

conn.Close();
```

This works just fine aside from the fact that I can't add the "Please select company" into the dropdownlist for some reason.

The weird issue is when I select a one of the entries, it just refreshes the page and does nothing else aside from making the second drop downlist visible and removing all data from the two lists.

The second issue is when I try to select both EmployerID and their name which and combine them into one column to be used in the dropdownlist instead of just the EmployerID alone like this

SqlCommand Cmd = new SQLCommand("SELECT EmployerID + ' - ' + Name AS CompanyName From Employer", conn);

I do not know how to use this dropdownlist.selectedvalue to call out the respective employee as I have no idea how to split the column back to its original two columns.

Thanks ~

Answer (score 2):

> I can't add the "Please select company" into the dropdownlist for some
>   reason.

You have to make sure that the `AppendDataBoundItems` is set to `true`.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCompanyList" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="--Please Select the Company--" Value="" />   
</asp:DropDownList>
```

> The weird issue is when I select a one of the entries, it just
>   refreshes the page and does nothing else aside from making the second
>   drop downlist visible and removing all data from the two lists.

I guess the reason for this is the classic error, you always databind the DropDownList, not only `if(!IsPostBack)`. So use this in `Page_Load`:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    MethodWhichDataBindsYourDropDownList();
}
```

> The second issue is when I try to select both EmployerID and their
>   name which and combine them into one column to be used in the
>   dropdownlist instead of just the EmployerID alone like this

You use only the `EmployerId`, use different values for the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField`

```
ddlCompanyList.DataTextField = "EmployerID";
ddlCompanyList.DataValueField = "EmployerName";
```

Then use this query:

```
string sql = "SELECT EmployerID, EmployerID + ' - ' + Name AS EmployerName From Employer";
SqlCommand Cmd = new SQLCommand(sql, conn);
```

Comment: Thanks! I found out the main issue was cause I actually had put the same dropdownlist for filling the employee which made it remove everything since the selectedvalue for employer would become nothing.

I don't actually know what to do after implementing your last query. When I'm selecting the employeeID + name using the EmployerID it works, but it still doesn't work if I use both